# ssl working for local ip not domain name

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

I have turned on ssl on my apache server using a self assigned certificate. If I go to my hostname (dev.local) I can see the https certificate warning which is what I expect when from https. However, if I go to my domains which are specified in my vhosts https doesn't work. This is a sample of what is in my httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/public_sites/domain
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
Alias /mt "/var/www/public_sites/mt"
ErrorLog "/logs/domain/error_log"
CustomLog "/logs/domain/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
        <Directory /var/www/public_sites/domain>
        AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/public_sites/domain
        ServerName domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

If I go to https://domain.com it doesn't work. But https://dev.local does work. If I go to the ip address of the server locally it works (192.168.0.194). If I go to the ip address of the external ip (my static ip dns uses) it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why that would be? Shouldn't it work since I put the NameVirtualHost and specifically a 443 virtualhost in the httpd file?

Comment: Wow, this sucks.  I actually found the exact question I need an answer to and it's closed as "Off Topic".  Thanks, casperOne.